# Catch blur and Enter click on <input> field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I follow other questions in StackOverflow to catch blur and enter click event, but it returns me the following:

> e is not defined

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="mpsRegnomer" er="невалиден номер" id="mpsRegnomer" class="upertrim inputGSmall" value="" style="margin-top:0px"/>
```

**JS**

```
$("#mpsRegnomer").bind("blur keyup", function(е) {
    console.log(e);
    loadPoliciesByRegNum();
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mdwnxps0/4/)

I want to catch the event and to use `e.keyCode === 13` for enter but also to work with `blur`. For example if type "123" and press enter to execute `loadPoliciesByRegNum()`

Comment: Read [the manual for bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). It is **deprecated** do not use it. It's replacement, `on`, has been around for *many* years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `e` in

```
.bind("blur keyup", function(е) {
```

is not a normal e, but the Unicode Symbol `U+0435 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE`. 
 Replace it by a normal `e`:

```
$("#mpsRegnomer").bind("blur keyup", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    loadPoliciesByRegNum();
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pbw8qsvg/

Answer (score 1):

`bind` gives the `context` of `this` to the `object/element` who invokes the `function`. In our case `input`. `e` which is passed inside the `function` `**is not defined and binding does not provide e the value of the element**`. Due to `bind` `this` refers to the `input`. You can use the `input` using `this` inside the `function` now.

```js
$("#mpsRegnomer").bind("blur keyup", function() {
    console.log(this);
    loadPoliciesByRegNum();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="mpsRegnomer" er="невалиден номер" id="mpsRegnomer" class="upertrim inputGSmall" value="" style="margin-top:0px"/>
```

```js
    $("#mpsRegnomer").on('keyup blur ', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13)
    alert("a")
        loadPoliciesByRegNum();
});
        


What you wanted to do can be done without bind using `on` in `jquery`
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" name="mpsRegnomer" er="невалиден номер" id="mpsRegnomer" class="upertrim inputGSmall" value="" style="margin-top:0px"/>
```